# Attach M4V Video To Email

Tags: iphone, ios, email

I am attempting to attach a video from the gallery to an email using the  MFMailComposeViewController in a seemingly standard way.

The video is recorded in a m4v format using the GPUImage framework and is being selected through a custom picker.

The picker returns me an ALAsset which I retrieve a URL from (I have launched this into the MPMoviePlayerViewController and it exists and plays fine).

When the email launches for a preview, it has a video icon where it thinks it has attached the video.

When I send this to an email address, the email has no attachment at all. Can you please help me find what is wrong the following code?

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailpicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] ;
    mailpicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    mailpicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal ;
    [mailpicker setSubject:@"Test email!"];
    NSData *movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[asset defaultRepresentation] url]];

    NSLog(@"%@", [[asset defaultRepresentation] url]);

    //I have tried all of the following;
    [mailpicker addAttachmentData:movieData mimeType:@"video/x-m4v" fileName:@"Video.m4v"];
    //[mailpicker addAttachmentData:movieData mimeType:@"application/m4v" fileName:@"Video.m4v"];
    //[mailpicker addAttachmentData:movieData mimeType:@"video/m4v" fileName:@"Video.m4v"];

    NSString *emailBody = @"Hey!";
    [mailpicker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailpicker animated:YES];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I didn't read the documents properly.

I've got to use the asset librarys assetForURL to get the video data.

For anyone else, take a look at this;

```
[assetLibrary assetForURL:YOURURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) // substitute YOURURL with your url of video
```

Be careful though, you may need to compress / downsize your video.